# dmidecode for RAM info, which speed is real speed info?

Tags: linux

When using the `dmidecode` command, we can see the speed of RAM:

```
Speed: 2933 MHz
```

and

```
Configured Clock Speed: 2666 MHz
```

Which one is the currently running speed? Why are there two speed items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dmidecode`’s output for memory, “Speed” is the highest speed supported by the DIMM, as determined by [JEDEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEDEC) SPD information. “Configured Clock Speed” is the speed at which it is currently running (as set up during boot).

The latter may be higher than the former, *e.g.* with DIMMs providing higher speeds described by [Intel XMP profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#XMP_extension).

Comment: This is close, but not quite right, looking at a data sample right now someone posted, configured speed appears to the speed the system booted at, and speed is more of a default value, in this case, speed was 1333 MT/S, and configured speed 1600 MT/S. Could be overclocking, could be just an odd set of values, but 1600 was in this case the actual speed, faster than speed value.

Comment: While providing details to a vendor for purchasing additional ram,  may I depend `dmidecode` output ?

Comment: @Arun the part number given by `dmidecode` can be trusted, and along with the manufacturer, will allow you to determine the exact characteristics of the installed memory.